# What are the key features I need to check before running a tensorflow job in PBS?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pbs

I am trying to run a deep learning job (developed in Tensorflow) in PBS but after 1 week I got error message `PBS: job killed: walltime 691231 exceeded limit 691200`. I'm new in PBS job hence I want to know what are the Key parameters I should change for a job to complete successfully. I have around 800k data patches. I kept batch size 32 and learning rate 3e-2. Present configuration of my system

```
node - we have 12, ppn - absolute max is 32
```

Present settings of my .PBS file ppn-4. I think I need to increase number of ppn. Is there any other keypoints which I need to alter for better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set PBS wall time using the below format. In your case, by default it was 8 days (192 hours) so job got killed after 192 hours.

walltime is in hh:mm:ss format.

**#PBS -l walltime=192:00:00**

Below is the command to check maximum wall time configured. Based on the "resources_max.walltime" , you can set the value in script.

$ qmgr -c "list queue batch"

Queue batch

```
    resources_max.nodes = 16

   **resources_max.walltime = 24:00:00**
    ----
```

Thanks,
Rajeswari Ponnuru.

Answer (score 0):

> You can increase the walltime by adding it in bash script before
>   running in qsub mode as shown below:

```
# PBS -l walltime=24:00:00
```